# Конвертация изображений png, jpg в webp с параллельным их сжатием через плагин vite-plugin-image-optimizer в сборщике Vite

Tags: javascript, изображения, npm, img, vite

Имеется сборка в Vite со следующей конфигурацией vite.config.js:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import injectHTML from 'vite-plugin-html-inject';
import { ViteImageOptimizer } from 'vite-plugin-image-optimizer';
import legacy from '@vitejs/plugin-legacy';

export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    inject: true
  },
  plugins: [
    [injectHTML()],
    ViteImageOptimizer({
      dir: 'public/images',
      outDir: 'dist/images',
      png: {
        quality: 80,
      },
      jpeg: {
        quality: 80,
      },
      jpg: {
        quality: 80,
      },
      webp: {
        lossless: true,
      },
    }),
    legacy({
      targets: ['defaults', 'not IE 11']
    }),
  ],
});
```

Плагин vite-plugin-image-optimizer помогает сжимать картинки забирая их из public/images и отправляя в dist/images, все работает отлично. Мне нужно также параллельно эти же самые картинки конвертировать в формат webp и сохранять по тому же пути для использования их в picture тэге. Возможно ли настроить данный плагин таким образом? В документации ничего не нашел. Если невозможно настроить, есть ли плагин, который будет не конфликтовать и параллельно конвертировать изображения?
Заранее спасибо.